# ASP.NET MVC Core, How to add a attribute to a input based on the DataType annotation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I add a attribute to a `<input />` tag based on the DataType using razor.

For instance if my data does have annotation

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)] 
public float Amount {get; set;}
```

Then I would like to have `<input name="Amount" class="currency" >` when using the tag helper `<input asp-for="Amount " />`

Comment: You would need to write you own custom`TagHelper` which uses reflection to read the value of the `DataType` enum to add the class

Comment: i created a nuget to help with such things. you can check this: http://netcoresimple.azurewebsites.net/docs/Generator
You can use a generator and create a custom razor template. The template is strongly typed and you can easily access the datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) suggested, you'll need to write a TagHelper for this. The TagHelper architecture will provide you with all you need.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace AnnotationBasedAttributes
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("input")]
    public class MyAwesomeTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public ModelExpression AspFor { get; set; }

        public override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            if (!(this.AspFor.Metadata is DefaultModelMetadata modelMetadata))
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            var dataTypeAttribute = modelMetadata.Attributes.Attributes.OfType<DataTypeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (dataTypeAttribute == null)
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            var type = dataTypeAttribute.DataType.ToString().ToLower();
            output.Attributes.Add(new TagHelperAttribute("class", type));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need to do anything special in your view. Just use the input tag helper as usual:

```
@model IndexModel

<label asp-for="Amount"></label>
<input asp-for="Amount" />
```

Just don't forget to tell your app to search for TagHelpers in your assembly. Do this in `_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@addTagHelper *, MyWebApplication
```